# Running PHP asynchronously

Tags: php, asynchronous

Given an input and a button in PHP, I need to enter an amount of time in the input and then press the button, it should execute a PHP function after that amount of time.

How do I do this?

EDIT:

**I don't need a client-side solution. This is a server-side problem.**

The JavaScript's timeout dies when the user leaves the page. I need that timeout still alive after the user leaves the page.

I haven't tried anything anything, I don't know how do this.

Comment: look at ajax http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: I edited the description, I need a server-side solution, the timeout must live after the user leaves the page. Thanks!

Comment: Use a cron job that checks a time in a database that will start a process once the time it hit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jon, How do I use the cron jobs?

Comment: Too large a topic to try and explain. Time to do some research ;)

Comment: I see. Now I know where to start research. :D

Answer (score 1):

Since almost all the time you work with data in the database, [creating an event in mysql](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/) might be an option. Furthermore if you manage to write all in mysql code, it would be faster than going back and forth from php to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had a similar need. Not sure if this works for you though. Let me know if it works or not.

```
if (isset($_GET['async'])) {

    for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
    {
        append_log(date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . ': background process.<br />');
        sleep(1);
    }

    exit;
}

header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
pseudo_async(array('async' => true));   // this runs this php script in the backbround

echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    output_buffer('appended to the log <br />');
    append_log(date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . ': main process.<br />');
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';


function pseudo_async($query) {

    $timeout = array('http' => array('timeout' => 0.01));
    $context = stream_context_create($timeout);

    @file_get_contents(selfurl() . '?' . http_build_query($query), false, $context);
}

function append_log($msg) {
    $file = __DIR__ . '/log.html';
    file_put_contents($file, $msg, FILE_APPEND);
}

function selfurl() {
    $pageURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    else 
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    return $pageURL;
}

function output_buffer($str) {
    echo $str;
    flush();
    ob_flush(); 
}
```